# Unable to get the latest version 5.0.3 of Angular Material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to install to the latest 5.0.3 using the below commands

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

or

```
npm install --save @angular/material@latest @angular/cdk@latest
```

but in vain, every time i got the below version in the package.json:
"@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0"
"@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0"

The application is running on Anguar 5.0.0.

Any idea how to get the latest one.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: is there a package-lock.json in the directory where you run npm install?

Comment: Yes, there is one, i deleted it and when i try to install the latest version it pull the 5.0.0-rc0 version.

Comment: have you tried with `npm install --save @angular/material@latest`? Do you get the latest when you run `npm show @angular/material version`?

Comment: Yes, i did, but the issue continue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling?

EDIT: Can you try moving the `node_modules` folder and then run this command:

```bash
npm i
```

Comment: I'm running Windows 7, i already deleted the node_module without success.

Comment: Did you move the `node_modules` folder to the trash, then run `npm install` again?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the production version in npm registery   point to the 5.0.0-rc0 version.

Comment: NB: The application is running on Anguar 5.0.0 version. do I need to upgrade to the latest one?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by upgrading my npm version to 5.6.0.